# rails pipeline css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, stylesheet

I am using `rails 3.2.12` and created a css file in `assets/stylesheets/equipment.css` to go along with a controller called `equipment_controller.rb`.  This stylesheet isn't working. What do I need to do to get this included in the pipeline?

Comment: Can you explain what's not working? Rails will automatically compile embedded Ruby or SCSS if you edit the filename extension, e.g. `equipment.css.scss` or even `equipment.css.scss.erb`.

Comment: restarted the server?

Answer (score 1):

The file needs to be loaded into your `application.css`.

In your `application.css` file, you will either need to load the file manually (by adding `require equipment` to the manifest at the top of the file), or it will also be included if you have a `require_tree` line.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the `*= require_tree .` in your `application.css`. It will be responsible to include all stylesheets from the current directory.

Comment: *=require_tree . is in my application.css.  Any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the contents and changed the extension from .css to .css.scss.  And now it works.

Comment: the extension should make no difference.... maybe clearing the contents did the trick...